# When printing layout page it does not show the actual cards

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, automation, data-merge

I am designing a game cards. I merged the layout of the single master card with csv file,as you can see on the pictures below. After that I made a printing layout page using rectangle frame tool and placed the source of the layout for single cards. How to force to Indesign to print the actual texts on the cards and not the layout of the master card ?

Thank you very much.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `Create Merged Document` feature for the actual data to be pulled from the CSV into the Data Merge fields and baked into a new file, which can then be:

1. distributed in a grid as multiple records per page (see images below)
2. printed

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this create a new document with each data set on an individual page? I think the question is how to create the merged document and have each card imposed onto 1 sheet for printing.

Comment: With the proper setup, this panel gives the option to create MULTIPLE RECORDS PER PAGE. I have done this myself. You set up one entry, then this panel can define a set of rules for duplicating that entry a number of times PER PAGE. Like, you can place 6 entries PER ONE PAGE, or 9, or 12, or whatever you need. Just added one more image to my answer to illustrate this.